# android application crash due to problems with sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, crash

I'm trying to write an application and I want to use sql for my database. I have a problem with the commands in almost every query.
This is my DBAdapter.java file:

```
public class DBAdapter {

static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
static final String KEY_HOUR_BEGIN = "hour_begin";
static final String KEY_HOUR_END = "hour_end";
static final String KEY_TEM_NAME = "tem_name";
static final String KEY_PERCENT = "percent";
static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MYDB";
static final String DATABASE_TABLE_TEMPLATE = "template";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TEMPLATE = 
        "create table template (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        "tem_name text not null, hour_begin text not null, hour_end text not null, " +
        "percent text not null";


final Context context;

DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        try{
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TEMPLATE);
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Updating database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
    + newVersion + ", which will all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS template");
        onCreate(db);

    }
}

//opens the database
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//closes the database
public void close()
{
    DBHelper.close();
}

            //insert template into the database
            public long insertTemplate(String tem_name, String hour_begin, String hour_end, String percent)
            {
                ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
                initialValues.put(KEY_TEM_NAME, tem_name);
                initialValues.put(KEY_HOUR_BEGIN, hour_begin);
                initialValues.put(KEY_HOUR_END, hour_end);
                initialValues.put(KEY_PERCENT, percent);
                return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_TEMPLATE, null, initialValues);
            }

            //deletes a particular template
            public boolean deleteTemplate(long rowId)
            {
                return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_TEMPLATE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
            }

            //retrieves all the template
            public Cursor getAllTemplates()
            {
                return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_TEMPLATE, new String[] 
                        {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TEM_NAME, KEY_HOUR_BEGIN, KEY_HOUR_END, 
                        KEY_PERCENT}, null, null, null, null, null);
            }

            //retrieves a particular template
            public Cursor getTemplate(long rowId) throws SQLException
            {
                Cursor mCursor = 
                        db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_TEMPLATE, new String[]
                                {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TEM_NAME, KEY_HOUR_BEGIN, KEY_HOUR_END, 
                                KEY_PERCENT}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                                null, null, null, null, null);
                if(mCursor != null)
                {
                    mCursor.moveToFirst();
                }
                return mCursor;
            }

            //updates a template
            public boolean updateTemplate(long rowId, String tem_name, String hour_begin, String hour_end, String percent)
            {
                ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
                args.put(KEY_TEM_NAME, tem_name);
                args.put(KEY_HOUR_BEGIN, hour_begin);
                args.put(KEY_HOUR_END, hour_end);
                args.put(KEY_PERCENT, percent);
                return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE_TEMPLATE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
            }
```

}

And this is my mainActivity.java
This is in the onCreate function:

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();

    //inserting template
    long id = db.insertTemplate("morning", "06:00", "14:00", "125");

    //getting all the templates
    Cursor c = db.getAllTemplates();
    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            DisplayTemplate(c);
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }

    //getting one template
    Cursor c = db.getTemplate(1);
    if(c.moveToFirst())
        DisplayTemplate(c);
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "template not found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //updating one template
    if(db.updateTemplate(1, "fgdhjf", "12:30:", "20:32", "200"))
        Toast.makeText(this, "update successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "update unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //deleting one template
    if(db.deleteTemplate(5))
        Toast.makeText(this, "delete successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "delete unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    db.close();
```

This is the DisplayTemplate function out of the onCreate function:

```
private void DisplayTemplate(Cursor c) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "template_id: " + 
c.getString(0) + "\n" + "name: " + 
            c.getString(1) + "\n" + 
"hour begin: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" + 
            "hour end: " + c.getString(3) + 
            "\n" + "percent: " + c.getString(4), 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I have problems with every function in the mainActivity. I checked with the debugger and the problem is with the DBAdapter file. Could please someone tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: post your logcat trace...

Comment: my logCat is completely empty

Comment: If you are getting logcat output, just close your emulator once and start it again.

Comment: "android application crash" -- please examine LogCat to find the Java stack trace associated with your crash. "my logCat is completely empty" -- then you are not looking at LogCat correctly. If you are using Eclipse, go to the DDMS tab, and select the device or emulator you are testing with in the Devices view. That should then populate the LogCat view with the LogCat from that device or emulator. "I have problems with every function in the mainActivity" -- until you tell us what these "problems" are, nobody can help you.

Comment: Okay, but what to write in the message box? It runs constantly. How to get the information you need. I run the application through my phone - galaxy s2 i9100

Comment: I used the debugger and found out the it throws an exception on this line: db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_MONTHLY_WAGE);. And DATABASE_CREATE_MONTHLY_WAGE = "create table monthlyWage (_id integer primary key autoincrement, month text not null, year text not null, working_days text not null, total_hours text not null,, hour_100 text not null, hour_125 text not null, hour_150 text not null, hour_175 text not null, hour_200 text not null, hour_225 text not null, hour_250 text not null, hour_275 text not null, hour_300 text not null, trips text not null, salary text not null);";

Answer (score 0):

It was a minor problem with the syntax. Thats all. Thank you for your time